# The wait operation timed out - Lengthen Timeout Period

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a grid view that is populated on a button click event:

```
    <asp:GridView CssClass="hoursGrid" ID="hoursReportGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84"
        BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" OnRowDataBound="hoursReportGridView_OnRowDataBound" DataKeyNames="DifferentUsers, DoubleBookedFlag, PointPerson, Person">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Person" HeaderText="Person" SortExpression="Project" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Project" HeaderText="Project" SortExpression="Project" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectType" HeaderText="Project Type" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Sprint" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Theme" HeaderText="Theme" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Theme" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StoryNumber" HeaderText="Story Number" SortExpression="Story" ItemStyle-Width="6%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StoryTitle" HeaderText="Story Title" SortExpression="Story" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Effort" HeaderText="Effort" SortExpression="Effort" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Task" HeaderText="Task" SortExpression="Task"  ItemStyle-Width="20%" HtmlEncode="false" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OriginalEstimateHours" HeaderText="Original Estimate" SortExpression="OriginalEstimateHours" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Monday" HeaderText="Mon" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Monday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Tuesday" HeaderText="Tues" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Tuesday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Wednesday" HeaderText="Wed" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Wednesday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Thursday" HeaderText="Thurs" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Thursday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Friday" HeaderText="Fri" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Friday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Saturday" HeaderText="Sat" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Saturday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Sunday" HeaderText="Sun" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Sunday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="taskLinkButton" Text='<%# Eval("Total") %>' Enabled='<%# Eval("StoryTitle").ToString() != "" %>' runat="server" OnClick="taskLinkButton_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

C#:

```
private void generateReport()
{
    //set sql parameters
    SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["userParam"].DefaultValue = currentEntity;
    SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["startDateParam"].DefaultValue = startingDay.ToString();
    SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["endDateParam"].DefaultValue = endingDay.ToString();
    SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["orgTeamPK"].DefaultValue = orgTeam;
    SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["productId"].DefaultValue = productId;
    SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["theme"].DefaultValue = themeSelected;
    hoursReportGridView.DataBind();
}
```

The query can take up to 45 seconds in SSMS and is resulting in the website crashing:

> The wait operation timed out
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait
>   operation timed out

Until a more efficient query can be created, is it possible to make the timeout period longer so that the program wont crash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could increase the `CommandTimeout` property. Add the `OnSelecting` event handler of your `SqlDataSource`, and in your code behind add the following:

```
protected void SqlDataSource2_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.CommandTimeout = 60;
}
```